# why is it important to initialize everything in the __init__ method?

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Exploring `__init__` method.

I was trying to understand why its always forced on this statement: "it's important to initialize everything in the `__init__` method"

Can anyone help me to understand this?

> Why is it important to initialize everything in the `__init__` method?

Comment: Not everything, just what is needed

Comment: Where did you read that statement?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, from here ..https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 5):

> I was trying to understand why its always forced on this statement:
>   "it's important to initialize everything in the `__init__` method"

The quote you are referring to, the complete line is:

> It goes without saying, then, that an object should start in a valid
>   state as well, which is why it's important to initialize everything in
>   the `__init__` method.

The key take-away here is that ***the object should start in a valid state***; that is when you are creating a custom object (which is what you are doing with a class), you should make sure that the `__init__` method sets up an instance of the class (the object) so that it is ready to be used.

As the `__init__` method is the first method called when a new object is created of a class; it is the first place you have to initialize any settings required for that object.

It is not important to initialize *everything* but it is the first opportunity you have to setup any required settings for instances of that class.

If you want to know more about these special methods (like `__init__`) you can read about them at the documentation's section on the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__).

Answer (score 2):

Because it's the first method that will be executed once the object is created and receives the initialization parameters, example

```
class Some_Object():
    def __init__(self, some_value, another_value):
        print("I'm initializing with values:", some_value, another_value)
        self.some_value = some_value
        self.another_value = another_value
        print("I'm initialized")

my_object = Some_Object(1, 2)
```

Edit: Just to clarify, you should only initialize what is necessary for the object not everything. The `__init__` method is like the constructor method in other OOP languages